# ROS on gumstix for on-board processing

Tags: ros, opencv2, gumstix

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I wonder how good a gumstix can run a ROS-based application using "gumros"(for instance). For example this [link](http://www.techrepublic.com/photos/missed-out-on-raspberry-pi-herere-five-alternatives/6350450?seq=5) mentions that it has 512 MB of memory. I would like to know if this one is sufficient using gumros to build an application like doing pose estimation using openCV or similar.

What I see, one of my packages consumes about 100 MB on my laptop. But with gumstix, it still needs to install OS and install ROS etc, will it be capable? Any experience having this running in (almost)real-time or on-board(at least)?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48173/ros-on-gumstix-for-on-board-processing/) by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1053 on 2012-11-12

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://www.willowgarage.com/blog/2012/12/11/exploring-ros-turtlecore

It's been done.
Also, disk space shouldn't be an issue if you have an SD card.

---

Originally posted by [ajc](https://answers.ros.org/users/931/ajc/) with karma: 56 on 2012-12-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I spent some time a year and half ago working on a vision system using an Overo. I was using a pretty outdated ROS release (I think it was cturtle), but it was able to capture images using OpenCV API and transfer the files over wifi to a ground node. All that was done while ROS was doing flight control of the aerial vehicle, which was not small operation by any means. Strictly speaking, it wasn't real time control. When the system is loaded and the air space was busy with other wireless devices, I experienced ~300ms delay.

---

Originally posted by [Adam YH Lee](https://answers.ros.org/users/2738/adam-yh-lee/) with karma: 53 on 2013-01-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2